# How to Open LinkPost URL in SubTab Console?

Tags: service-cloud-console, feeditem

I am able to create LinkPost feed item in case console:

```
//Adding a Link post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = cId; //case id
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
post.LinkUrl = '/' + customObj.Id; //custom object record that attached to linkpost
insert post;
```

But when I click the url, it will open new browser tab.
Is it possible to open linkpost content in console subtab?

**Update**
I cannot fill javascript function in linkpost link url,

```
javascript:srcUp('/' + customObj.Id +'?isdtp=vw');
```

it shows error:

```
The link URL must start with http://, https:// or ftp://.
```

Is there any workaround to open linkpost content in console subtab?

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it but I found that there is a method **openSubtab()** that you can use.

> openSubtab()

Opens a new subtab (within a primary tab) that displays the content of a specified URL, which can be relative or absolute. You can also override an existing subtab. Use to open a new subtab on a primary tab via the primary tab's ID. This method is only available in API version 20.0 or later.
If there's an error opening the tab, the error code is reported in the JavaScript console.

> Below is the Syntax

```
sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId:String, url:URL, active:Boolean, tabLabel:String, id:String, (optional)callback:Function, (optional)name:String)
```

> Sample VF page Code

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">

    <A HREF="#" onClick="testOpenSubtab();return false">
        Click here to open a new subtab</A> 

    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/43.0/integration.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testOpenSubtab() {
            //First find the ID of the primary tab to put the new subtab in
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
        }

        var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
            //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can open a new subtab in it
            var primaryTabId = result.id;
            sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'http://www.salesforce.com', false, 
                'salesforce', null, openSuccess, 'salesforceSubtab');
        };

        var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
            //Report whether we succeeded in opening the subtab
            if (result.success == true) {
                alert('subtab successfully opened');
            } else {
                alert('subtab cannot be opened');
            }
        };
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Below is the Link for the Same

[openSubtab()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm)

Comment: I am able to open subtab in visualforce page, but this is not visualforce page. This is feed item post that appear in case feed

Comment: From Where you are inserting the FeedItem using Apex OR combination of Apex and VF?

Comment: From quick action + trigger in case feed. When quick action create a record, it will trigger to insert feeditem link post in case

Answer (score 1):

To open as a sub tab, you can use the ConnectAPI via apex to create the chatter post using the EntityLinkSegmentInput.  The [EntityLinkSegmentInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_entity_link_segment.htm) properly hyperlinks the url to be opened as a subtab.

```
ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput entityLinkSegment = new ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput();
entityLinkSegment.entityId = someCaseId;
```

See the apex below. We are creating a chatter post that says "A link that opens in the subtab" and a link that points to a related record. See below

```
String someCaseId = '500990000099d9NAAQ';
String someRelatedRecordId = 'A13220000012D9NXYZ'//the record you want to link to.
List<ConnectApi.FeedItemInput> feedInputs = new List<ConnectApi.FeedItemInput


ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'A link that opens in the subtab';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput entityLinkSegment = new ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput();
entityLinkSegment.entityId = someRelatedRecordId;
messageInput.messageSegments.add(entityLinkSegment);

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
input.body = messageInput;
input.subjectId = someCaseId;
input.visibility = ConnectApi.FeedItemVisibilityType.INTERNALUSERS;

ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), input);
```